# How can I have an iterative component in apex:repeat (like a counter)?

Tags: repeat

I have an apex:repeat component. In the repeating text output, I want a number to increment row to row.

I will go ahead and call out that I realize I could achieve this by replacing my controller list with a wrapper, so each iterated item has a corresponding number that way, but I'm wondering if there's a more direct native way to have a number increment over each repeat component before adding more overhead in case I'm missing something either obvious and native or more clever.

I hope this makes sense - please let me know if my question isn't clear or can be improved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update following comment from sfdcfox :**

**The wrapper solution to count row number is the "safest" solution because as per [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_variable.htm) using below `apex:variable` method as a counter is not officially support and may break in the future.**

Defining a counter in the markup using `apex:variable` and increment it inside the `apex:repeat`

```
<apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!0}" /> 
<apex:repeat value="{!someList}" var="item">
   <apex:outputText value="{!rowNum}"/>

   <!-- additional content here -->

   <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum+1}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: oh wow! I honestly thought I tried this before and must have had something wrong (maybe out of order) because this totally worked and definitely didn't when I tried haha. Thanks!

Comment: @NataliePaige N.B., Caution, etc... This method is not officially supported and may break in the future. It also has known limitations. You should prefer the wrapper you were talking about. [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_variable.htm#!): *Note: <apex:variable> does not support reassignment inside of an iteration component, such as <apex:dataTable> or <apex:repeat>. The result of doing so, e.g., incrementing the <apex:variable> as a counter, is unsupported and undefined.*

Comment: @sfdcfox i didn't know that this method was not officially supported, thanks for pointing this out

Comment: @NataliePaige i've revised my answer to alert on the risk of using `<apex:variable>` method, also to help others looking for an answer and who might missed the comments here

Comment: Thanks, easy solution. Still working in 2022